# How do I trap the timeout event in Visual Studio unit test harness?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

I am attempting within Visual Studio to test whether a socket blocks under certain conditions, which is desired. The basic approach is to set a unit test to time out, perform the blocking operation, and pass the test if the timeout expires.

I can do all of this, sort of:

```
  [TestMethod, Timeout(3000)]
    public void RockingSockingBlockingTest()
    {
        bool bPass = false;
        try
        {
            Socket sock = OpenSocket();
            int result = blocking_socket_call(sock, ....mumble, ...);
            ... work more here, maybe raising assertions or throwing exceptions .... 

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            bPass = true;
        }

        Assert.IsTrue(bPass);
    }
```

Well and good - I actually get an exception when the test times out, but I never seem to know in advance what type of exception is coming. It seems to depend on the code that is running when the timeout transpires. This means if I want to trap other exceptions within the block, I am out of luck.

Is there a school solution to this problem?